# using google map API or usual API for compiling android project in V2?

Tags: android, google-maps

In google map android V1 project, it should be compiled with google maps API not ordinary API. I wonder if the same story for google map android V2 also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Maps V2 has no dependency on the original Maps SDK add-on. You are welcome to set a plain Android build target on your project and skip the `<uses-library>` element. Maps V2 has its own set of dependencies, notably on OpenGL ES 2.0+ and the existence of the Play Services Framework.

Comment: Thanks. right, I tried both and I noticed it works with both of them!